# MAT sdk integration in Android

Tags: android, sdk, google-play, oncreate

I have published my app in playstore. And I want to integrate MAT (MobileAppTracking) sdk in the next update of app. What should I call to track the previous installs and next installs? How can I track all installs (including previous installs) and updates. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this................................................................. 
http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/22621001-Handling-Installs-prior-to-SDK-implementation